# Change Express view folder based on where is the file that res.render() is called

Tags: node.js, express

I would like to change the view folder of Express when I call res.render().

For example, if I call res.render(viewName) inside /folder/file.js, I would like that Express look for the view inside /folder/views.

If the file is inside /folder1/folder2/file.js, I would like that Express look for the view inside /folder1/folder2/views

Is it possible ?

Answer (score 155, accepted):

You can use the method `set()` to redefine express's default settings.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/yourViewDirectory'));
```

- [Express documentation](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.set)

For a dynamic path change you can do something like this:

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var app = express();

app.engine('jade', require('jade').__express);
app.set('view engine','jade');

app.customRender = function (root,name,fn) {

    var engines = app.engines;
    var cache = app.cache;

    view = cache[root+'-'+name];

    if (!view) {
        view = new (app.get('view'))(name, {
          defaultEngine: app.get('view engine'),
          root: root,
          engines: engines
        });

        if (!view.path) {
          var err = new Error('Failed to lookup view "' + name + '" in views directory "' + root + '"');
          err.view = view;
          return fn(err);
        }

        cache[root+'-'+name] = view;
    }

    try {
      view.render(opts, fn);
    } catch (err) {
      fn(err);
    }
}

app.get('/', function(req, res) {

    app.customRender(path.join(__dirname, '/path/to/user/'),'index',function (err,html) {
        if (err)
            res.send(404);
        else
            res.send(200,html);
    });

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: It looks good, but how can I make it dynamic? If two users access different paths at the same time, one of the app.set will overwrite the other, won't it?

Comment: Can you point me to the documentation regarding app.get('view')?  I can't seem to find it.   I don't see 'view' in the list here: http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#app.settings.table. I don't like the idea of using undocumented functions.

Comment: Late, but for others. 1. instead of dynamic, an array may be suitable. 2. It is now in the documents.

Answer (score 66):

Instead of simply passing your view name to the render function, you can pass a relative or​ ​absolute​​ ​path.​​​​​​

Simple example:

```
app.get('/your/path', function(req, res) {
    //viewname can include or omit the filename extension
    res.render(__dirname + '/folder/with/views/viewname'); 
});​​​​​​​​​​
```

Comment: This seems waaaay easier than overriding the rendering function!

Answer (score 16):

That's pretty simple

to change the view folder of Express when one calls res.render(),
just set the path where the views are located,
in your case,

```
app.set('views','./folder1/folder2/views');
```

This changes the path where Express would search for specified views.

Comment: this is best bcs it's most simple, no additional `require`. ...easy.

Comment: Correct @MonarchWadia

Comment: Does this introduce a race condition when multiple requests are resetting the view folder?

Answer (score 7):

Set the path of view location.

```
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
```

Set the view engine.

```
app.set('view engine','ejs');
```

Complete code will look like below.

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');

const app = express();

app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/views'));
app.set('view engine','ejs');

app.listen(3000, () => console.log('Application is running on'));
```

Answer (score 6):

*(Sorry I can't comment yet)*

[@nuzzolilo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21885377/change-express-view-folder-based-on-where-is-the-file-that-res-render-is-calle/34171560#34171560) works well. But if you prefer ES6

```
app.get('/path', function (req, res) {
    res.render(`${__dirname}/templates_dir/index`, { data: "value" });
});
```

This simply improves code readability ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can also get the relative path by using `require.resolve`:
`res.render(require.resolve('./folder/with/views/viewname'));`